# Kepler prediction problem, fundamentals of astrodynamics

Tags: physics, mathematics, astrodynamics

I needed help with problem 4.3 of *Fundamentals of Astrodynamics* by Roger R. Bate, Donald D. Mueller, Jerry E. White ([dover](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486600610.html), [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/BateMuellerAndWhiteFundamentalsOfAstrodynamics/Bate%2C%20Mueller%2C%20and%20White%20-%20Fundamentals%20of%20Astrodynamics_djvu.txt))

Given that $r_0 = (I+j)$ and $v_0 = 2k$ find $r$ and $v$ for difference in true anomaly 60°...

I tried this problem but had no way of finding the universal variable X for the first iteration, if anyone could help me with this it would be appreciated.

---

Here is a screen shot of the question in response to comments, from [books.google.com.in](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=UEC9DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187&dq=problem+4.3+fundamentals+of+astrodynamics&source=bl&ots=1tM2Nd01aE&sig=ACfU3U2hojHegkPjGisTaHRHKRz3uI04Jw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAk87Nn4HqAhUMA3IKHbxzB7cQ6AEwAXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=problem%204.3%20fundamentals%20of%20astrodynamics&f=false):

> [image: Question 4.3 in Fundamentals of Astrodynamics by Bate, Mueller & White]

Comment: @DavidHammen the difference in true anomaly part is the angle travelled in the elliptical orbit by the body is 60°

Comment: @JCRM I was able to solve the other problems but the main difference was chapter 4 teaches you to predict for the time given but it's not clear when the only given is the angular travel of the body in the orbit

Comment: you'll need to calculate the time first then

Comment: Apparently I was taking the wrong formula of  eccentric anomaly for hyperbolic orbits which was the error.....I got the answer finally

Comment: @user36620 I've included the MathJax for the first part of the question, why not go ahead and update your post and finish it then? *Thanks!*

Comment: If you figured it out on your own, you can provide an answer here to help out others in the future. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Comment: @called2voyage oh okay.....so basically frost you find a,p,e of the orbit which comes out to be hyperbolic. Then you find out the initial true anomaly from r0,v0 and add 60° to it to get final true anomaly....convert it to eccentric anomaly and then calculate for x based on the formula x=sqrt(a).(change in eccentric anomaly) and find f,g,f dot,g dot.

Comment: @user36620 Oh, I meant in an actual answer post below :)